# How to use data_control_bulk_data_h in Tizen data control?

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

I want to learn data_control_bulk_ ... methods usage but except doc I see nothing to learn from about it. Is it interchangeable with `data_control_h`? I want an example.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.tizen.org/application/native/api/mobile/5.5/group__CAPI__DATA__CONTROL__CONSUMER__MODULE.html#gaf8891d1ab8c938ada38f9668c2c9fa52

You can see the API reference

It is not interchangeable with `data_control_h`.
See the code below. However, it is not complete code.
So you need to change the sample code

```
/* provider application */

void bulk_insert_request_cb(int request_id, data_control_h provider, 
data_control_bulk_data_h bulk_data_h, void *user_data)
{
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "[bulk insert_request_cb] %d", request_id);

data_control_bulk_result_data_h result_data_h;
char* command = NULL;
int i, ret;
int count;
long long inserted_row_id;
bundle *data;

data_control_bulk_data_get_count(bulk_data_h, &count);
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "[bulk insert_request_cb] count %d", count);
data_control_bulk_result_data_create(&result_data_h);
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    data_control_bulk_data_get_data(bulk_data_h, i, &data);
    command = data_control_provider_create_insert_statement(provider, data);
    ret = sqlite3_exec(db, command, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    free(command);
    if (ret != SQLITE_OK) {
        data_control_bulk_result_data_add(result_data_h, data, sqlite3_errcode(db));
        continue;
    }
    dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "insert success");
    inserted_row_id = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db);
    data_control_bulk_result_data_add(result_data_h, data, DATA_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE);
}

ret = data_control_provider_send_bulk_insert_result(request_id, result_data_h);
if (ret != DATA_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE) {
    dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG,
            "send_bulk_insert_result failed with error: %d",ret);
}
data_control_bulk_result_data_destroy(result_data_h);
}

void initialize_datacontrol_provider()
{
data_control_provider_sql_register_insert_bulk_data_request_cb(bulk_insert_request_cb, NULL);
    if (result != DATA_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE)
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "data_control_provider_sql_register_insert_bulk_data_request_cb failed with error: %d", result);
    else
        dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, LOG_TAG, "Provider SQL Bulk register success");
}

/* Consumer Application */

int insert_bulk_data() 
{                                                                            
data_control_bulk_data_h bulk_data_h;                                       
bundle *b1;                                                                 
bundle *b2;                                                                 
int req_id;                                                                 
int result;                                                                 
int count;                                                                  

result = data_control_sql_register_insert_bulk_data_response_cb(<your handle>, <your         response cb>, NULL);
assert_eq_with_exit(result, DATA_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE);                       

b1 = bundle_create();                                                       
bundle_add_str(b1, "WORD", "'bulk test'");                                  
bundle_add_str(b1, "WORD_DESC", "'bulk test description'");                 
b2 = bundle_create();                                                       
bundle_add_str(b2, "WORD", "'bulk test'");                                  
bundle_add_str(b2, "WORD_DESC", "'bulk test description'");                 

data_control_bulk_data_create(&bulk_data_h);                                
data_control_bulk_data_add(bulk_data_h, b1);                                
data_control_bulk_data_add(bulk_data_h, b2);                                

data_control_bulk_data_get_count(bulk_data_h, &count);                      
dlog_print(DLOG_INFO, "NativeTCT", "bulk insert count %d", count);          

__correct_row_cnt = count;                                                  
result = data_control_sql_insert_bulk_data(g_provider, bulk_data_h, &req_id);
assert_eq_with_exit(result, DATA_CONTROL_ERROR_NONE);                       

data_control_bulk_data_destroy(bulk_data_h);                                
bundle_free(b1);                                                            
bundle_free(b2);                                                            
}
```